# Issue with <section> tag on a page not taking me to the correct section

Tags: html

I'm having an functionality issue with a web page that I'm working on.

I'm using `<section>` tags to define sections that I can jump to from the navigation bar.

When I click the nav link 'HOTEL' it should take me to `<section id="hotel">`. For some reason, this isn't happening. I am taken to `<section id="events"`.

There do not appear to be any issues with the other section tags, is there anything that jumps out as an obvious problem?

http://robertmegone.com/wedding/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `clear:both` css to your section hotel

Comment: That's done it, many thanks! Would you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: you have  #fh5co-event in the event section that is float:left that is causing the section to not be cleared.